# When I switch to https, my pages return a 404 error in Mono + Apache

Tags: asp.net, apache, https, mono, apache2

I am using Mono + Apache for ASP.Net and when I go to the https version of my site it asks if I want to accept the certificate (I check to save it permanently) but then it shows a 404 error page! None of my pages show up under https. How do I fix this?

(What info do you need me to post to help diagnose this?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem: Apache had a default "example" virtual host file to handle SSL requests. Even though I'd created my own, that one was taking precedence, so the directory of that virtualhost was being served for SSL.